# Facebook PHP SDK version 5 Session Issue

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, laravel-5.3

I am trying to get facebook page feeds with facebook php sdk 5 but Facebook Session not working and i m getting this error

Class 'Facebook\FacebookSession' not found

**Code Detail**

```
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($fbAppId, $fbAppSecret);
$session = new FacebookSession('access-token');
$session = FacebookSession::newAppSession();

request = new FacebookRequest(
                $session,
                'GET',
                '/' . $fbPageId . '/feed'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
```

Comment: That’s because you are using code that was written for the SDK version 4. Go check the docs, there’s lots of examples for the current version.

Comment: can you please give me any reference page url

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted

Answer (score 0):

If you need just the facebook page feeds you can also use

- the [Facebook page plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin)  or
- the [Famax jQuery plugin](http://www.codehandling.com/2015/03/free-version-of-famax-jquery-plugin-is.html).